# ZK how to close popup window automatically without clicking any button?

Tags: java, listener, zk

I am showing some notifications in a `popup window` and I want to close that `window` after few seconds automatically. Is there any way to close that `window` without clicking any `button`?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I will suggest use Client.showNotification() ;

Comment: i am opening a popup window in that case how i will use Client.showNotification() ;

Comment: What exactly you are doing show some code how someone will know what the exact issue

Answer (score 1):

In your zul

```
<window id="main" apply="MyComposer">
<timer id="close" delay="1000" repeats="false"/>
<window id="popup" visible="false">
....
```

in java

```
class MyComposer extents SelectorComposer {

@Wire
Window popup
@Wire
Timer close

public void openPopup {
  popup.setVisible(true);
  popup.doPopup();
  Timer.start();
}

@Listen("onTimer #close")
public void close(Event event) {
  popup.detach();
}

}
```